# CSV to nested JSON using NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to create nested json from csv using nifi -
CSV file:

"Foo",12,"newyork","North avenue","123213"
"Foo1",12,"newyork","North avenue","123213"
"Foo2",12,"newyork","North avenue","123213"

Required Json:

```
{
    "studentName":"Foo",
    "Age":"12",
    "address__city":"newyork",
    "address":{
        "address__address1":"North avenue",
        "address__zipcode":"123213"
    }
}
```

I am using nifi 1.4 convertRecord Processor by applying avro schema but not able to get the nested json.

Avro schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "MyClass",
  "namespace" : "com.test.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "studentName",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "Age",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "address__city",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "address",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "address",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "address__address1",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "address__zipcode",
        "type" : "string"
      } ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: I am getting error :IllegalTypeConversionException

Comment: Is it possible to create nested json from csv using NiFi?

Comment: Can you provide the full stracktrace from niif-app.log for the IllegalTypeConversion?

Comment: Cannot convert value [North avenue] of type class java.lang.String to Object Array for field address
org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.IllegalTypeConversionException: Cannot convert value [North avenue] of type class java.lang.String to Object Array for field address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to:

1. Split your flowfile into individual records using SplitRecord
2. Convert from CSV to flat JSON files using ConvertRecord
3. Use the JOLT transform processor to transform your flat JSON into nested JSON objects in your desired format.

Comment: Thanks for the help@John Doe , I am using JOLT transform Processor and able to convert csv to nested JSON.